# Wordpress pre_get_posts and date_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the pre_get_posts hook to change the yearly archive results so that it shows me posts over the academic year instead. I'm using Wordpress version 3.9.2.

```
function get_posts_by_academic_year($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_year()) {
            $query->set('date_query', array(
                array(
                    'after' => array(
                            'year' => $year
                            , 'month' => 9
                            , 'day' => 1
                        ),
                    'before' => array(
                            'year'  => $year+1
                            , 'month' => 8
                            , 'day'   => 31
                        ),
                    'inclusive' => true
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'get_posts_by_academic_year');
```

I get nothing but a 404 page and no errors to help me debug this. You'll have to excuse my ignorance when it comes to Wordpress I don't use it very often. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or whether there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason will be that your $year variable is empty...

Populate it from the $query variable passed to the function...

$year = get_query_var( 'year' );

For some reason i got a 404 page error when the query return zero results... rather than there being a problem with the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_year() && $query->is_archive()) {
```